Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (vllm)
I was trying to install vllm for my project and it shows like this:
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '-j=20', '--target=moe_C', 'target=_C', '--target=_punica_C']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for vllm
Failed to build vllm
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects
What is the error possibly, i can't understand
